# How to set unique values only for the child model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following related models:

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    type_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64, unique=True)
    type_description = models.TextField(max_length=512, blank=True)


class DeviceTypeMarker(models.Model):
    marker_status = IntegerField()
    marker_status_text = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    marker = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/types/')
    marker_device_type = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='marker')
```

Where it is possible to define many `DeviceType` elements. For every `DeviceType` element there can be many **different** `marker_status`, `marker_status_text` and `marker`. The thing is that I **don't** want that inside a single `DeviceType` these elements are duplicated. They can be repeated but only in an another `DeviceType`.

For example, if type1 is a `DeviceType` object, then there can be only a `marker_status` with value "1", only a `marker_status_text`with value "error" and the same for `marker`. This values could only be repeated in an other `DeviceType` object. For example, type2..

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you should add [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) with all fields that should be unique together

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['marker_status', 'marker_status_text', 
                   'marker', 'marker_device_type'], 
            name='unique_for_device')
    ]
```

Comment: ok thanks, but how can i do a value unique? I mean if i already have a marker_status with value 0 then i want to make not possible to add another marker_status with the same value for the same type..

Comment: you have to add constraint for each combination of fields that should be unique together,  so for instance in this case marker_device_type and marker_status

Comment: ok yes i just did that and it works! Thank you!